# SWT GTK 64 bit and UBUNTU 11.04 NPE

Tags: 64-bit, swt, nullpointerexception, ubuntu-11.04

I'm currently working in an SWT standalone application. We usually work with windows but I'd like to work in Ubuntu.I set up the following environment.

Ubuntu 11.04 64bit
Java 6 update 27 64 bit
Eclipse Java EE 3.5 Galileo 64 bit
I'm using SWT GTK 64 bit

I've got a few classes extending different SWT widgets.

For example

```
    public class MyCombo extends Combo implements CellEditor<Long> {
    private Set<ListenerRef> listeners = new HashSet<ListenerRef>();

@Override
    public void addListener(int eventType, Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(new MyCombo.ListenerRef(eventType, listener));
        super.addListener(eventType, listener);
    }

 @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
        // Do nothing
    }
.
.
.
```

This code works perfectly well in Windows 7 64 bit, running SWT32 bit and java32 bit, from eclipse 32 bit.

In Ubuntu 11.04 I get a NPE (NullPointerException) when trying to add a listener, it seems that the listeners set is null, but it shouldn't cause that set should be initialized as for the code above, and as I say it works in Windows 7

First I had problems running the SWT 32 bit app in Ubuntu64 bit cause there's seem to be a bug when running 32 apps in 64 ubuntu, so I tried to run it with the 64 version, and now I'm getting this error. If I avoid this NPE checking the set, I end up getting a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.accessibility.Accessible.isValidThread(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.accessibility.Accessible.checkWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.accessibility.Accessible.addRelation(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas of what could be the reason? Are you aware of this problem in previous Ubuntu distrubutions? I don't get this problems in Windows 7, at least running SWT 32 bit

Please let me know if you need more details

Thanks and regards

BTW I forgot, SWT is 3.7 in Linux and 3.6.2 in Windows

Comment: Did you try running your JVM with -XstartOnFirstThread?